# Transparency of Image Empties not working

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to setup my blueprints in Blender, and I've more or less achieved it, but the image empties are not displaying the pictures well.

Edit: I think this picture more clearly describes my problem
[image]

What is going on with the rendering?? It's like impossible architecture.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the front ortho? What exactly are you after? It looks like you have both empties' transparency enabled, that will make one empty always show through, depending on the selection.

Comment: In my opinion, For those kind of blueprints, images as background would work better

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45471/how-to-assign-different-background-images-for-different-3d-views

Comment: As for the transparency... what format are the images in? Do they have an alpha channel?

Comment: If your image does have an alpha channel, make sure it is enabled: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QU0k3.gif

Comment: @360ueck: I can't add a picture of the front as I don't have enough rep to do so. I'm trying to get them to work like in 3DS Max, as in if I view the setup from the front, I should see the front blueprint, and if I view from the back, I should see the back blueprint.

Comment: @cegaton: I tried, and didn't really like the background method. It's hard to get all the blueprints to align. Also, they don't have an alpha channel.

Comment: Try change the OpenGL clip-alpha user preference.

Comment: @PythonNewbie to align the images to be used as background you can move them using the X and Y values, rotation and size.

Comment: @Python Newbie I found that annoying when I first joined SE as well. I think maybe 4 pictures would be a good minimum, not 2. I added an answer to your question, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no transparency level set, and all transparency options enabled (for all objects), blender defaults to complete transparency of all objects except the one selected, and behaves similar to x-ray.

To achieve the kind of transparency you'd like, follow these 2 steps:

**1)** Set a transparency level in properties> data (here I've set both images to 0.35).

[image: Image 1]

**2)** Enable transparency in properties> object.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Playing with the Transparency option, I've found it works exactly like X-Ray: The object that has transparency checked in the objects property panel will always show. I've found that disabling transparency for the top and side blueprints, and enabling it for the front works best, but I still cannot get blender to display the rear blueprint when I am viewing the model from the rear. It always displays the front blueprint, even when I disable transparency for everything and have nothing selected.

Comment: @PythonNewbie Did you try setting transparency to 0.34 (**for every object**) in data? (Step 1). If you don't, one object will always act as x-ray, since the default transparency value is 1 (opaque). The reason your work around is working is because when you enable transparency without setting a value, you are essentially making the object opaque. Which is fine, but when transparency is enabled on at least one other object, it behaves as x-ray (not transparency). I'm sure the physics is relatively correct, but it's not what your looking for; which is why your having to work around it.

Comment: Yes I did, and it's still showing only one image both front and back view. I guess this is just a limitation of Blender's, although I have NO IDEA why it happens. 3DS Max was so much easier =P

Comment: The answer is here for the new UI https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159363/how-do-you-fix-opacity-to-a-reference-image-in-blender-2-81