# How do you fix opacity to a reference image in blender 2.81

Tags: edit-mode

As the title says, how do we adjust the opacity to a reference image brought in the viewport? I can't find the Opacity in Properties Window of the respective image. I've seen some older versions of blender with the opacity available. Is it gone in 2.81? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

With Image selected : **Image Properties panel** > enable **Alpha** and adjust **Transparency**.

[image]

Comment: Has this changed in 2.83? Because there is option like "Use Alpha"