# How do I change to Left, Right, Front, Back Ortho Perspectives?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, image, orthographic

I'm new to Blender and I am trying to model an old truck. The tutorials I have been working with all say to have it in Ortho perspective and choose the view i want it in. I changed it to Ortho and it automatically goes to Camera Ortho. If I try to adjust the view to top, back, front, etc. It changes back to camera perspective. The tutorials show that each window should be dedicated to a specific angle (top ortho, back ortho, etc.) I've read that perspectives automatically changes in the newer version when you move the camera. Is that why? I can't seem to figure it out.

Also, for some reason the background images only show if I enter them in as "all views" The tutorials tell me to enter them as "front, top, back" etc., per the view the image is. But when I tried that, it wouldn't show up. I must be doing something wrong.

I have found a few answers on the forum that are tangentially related to this, but hasn't been working for me at the moment. Thank you in advance for any advice or links you provide.[image: I need the perspective to be correct, so that I can adjust the planes to begin modeling.]

Comment: Numpad 5 toggles ortho / persp 1 is front, 3 is right 7 is top. ctl - 1 for left etc. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45471/how-to-assign-different-background-images-for-different-3d-views . You currently have an ortho camera aligned to views. Not sure you need to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Lets try to clarify a few things:

### Camera Settings vs. Viewport Settings

[image: Viewport vs Camera]

Camera and Viewport are two different things:

- Viewport is mainly for temporary navigating and inspecting the 3d scene
- Camera is mainly for defining final rendering perspective
- You can switch Perspective/Orthographic for both Viewport and Camera separately → 1.
- You can change focal length for both Viewport and Camera separately → 2.
- You can set the Viewpoint of the Viewport, without changing the camera → 3.

And here the two of them get mixed up a bit:

- If you set the Viewport to Viewpoint>Camera, it will adopt the Camera's parameters without changing them, but will switch back to its own viewport parameters on rotation/change of viewpoint. → 3.
- If Lock Camera to View is activated while in Camera Viewpoint the viewport will be linked to the camera parameters any viewport change will directly be applied to the cameras position and parameters.

### Viewport Background Images

- Background Images assigned to front, top, back, etc Axis are only shown if the viewport is in the corresponding viewpoint (front, top, etc.) and set to orthographic mode.
  (you seem to be in Camera Viewpoint with an orthographic Camera instead)