# background image disappears when opening blender

Tags: modeling

the background image I loaded into orto Right, top, disappears when opening blender (It is no longer imported / loaded) and oh yes, I already tried with fake user button too, no result. It's so annoying having to add all background images again. Why doesn't the save function work? Doesn't blender remember i added background images? I tried packing them also, doesn't work.
I'm using sensei format. Could that be the problem? Any tips?
Cheers.

Comment: To me, this works... (I have retried just now to be sure). Do you mean having these images kept with a blend file, or be present just opening Blender ?

Comment: be present just opening blender.

Comment: To do that you may open blender, set them up and go to the file menu, then 'save startup file'. The start up file is considered as your default opening Blender configuration

Comment: Open blender, open the project and make sure you have the Load UI box enabled see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45024/packed-images-used-as-background-dont-show-up-when-reopening-the-file/45027#45027

Comment: ok... so @cegaton's solution surely

Comment: Pack the image into the file. And use the Load UI button.